# Encryption decryption using PKCS#7

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, pkcs#7

I want to encrypt decrypt data using PKCS #7.
While exploring i found a book **Beginning Cryptography With Java**
In ch 9 of the book is having a example  code is below

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessable;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;

/**
 * Example of generating a detached signature.
 */
public class SignedDataExample
    extends SignedDataProcessor
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        KeyStore         credentials = Utils.createCredentials();
        PrivateKey       key = (PrivateKey)credentials.getKey(
                                          Utils.END_ENTITY_ALIAS, Utils.KEY_PASSWD);
        Certificate[]    chain = credentials.getCertificateChain(
                                                           Utils.END_ENTITY_ALIAS);
        CertStore        certsAndCRLs = CertStore.getInstance(
                                "Collection", new CollectionCertStoreParameters(
                                                      Arrays.asList(chain)), "BC");
        X509Certificate  cert = (X509Certificate)chain[0];

        // set up the generator
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

        gen.addSigner(key, cert, CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA224);
        gen.addCertificatesAndCRLs(certsAndCRLs);

        // create the signed-data object
        CMSProcessable data = new CMSProcessableByteArray(
                                                     "Hello World!".getBytes());

        CMSSignedData signed = gen.generate(data, "BC");

        // re-create
        signed = new CMSSignedData(data, signed.getEncoded());

        // verification step
        X509Certificate rootCert = (X509Certificate)credentials.getCertificate(
                                                                Utils.ROOT_ALIAS);
        if (isValid(signed, rootCert))

        {
           System.out.println("verification succeeded");
        }
        else
        {
           System.out.println("verification failed");
        }
     }
  }
```

I have couple of question

1. Where is encrypted data and how do i write it to file
2. How do i recover back original data from encrypted data
3. Do i need to send  key store to the person who is decrypting the encrypted data.
4. In what format should i send encrypted data

**Thanks A Lot**

Comment: The posted code does not contain anything encryption related. It is about generating a pkcs7 message signature for the sample message "Hello World!". therefore none of your questions can be answered.

Comment: Note that CMS containers can be used both for encrypting data as well as for signing data. Please look again; I'm pretty sure it should be in there somewhere.

Comment: Can you please tell me, which class i need to use in order to encrypt and decrypt using CMS ??

Comment: IS Enveloping data is the same as Encrypting the data ??

Comment: Is there a way in which i can write *CMSSignedData* to file as byte and make again object of *CMSSignedData* from that byte ?